# Raycasting from a specific point

Tags: python, gpu, vtk, raytracing, raycasting

I need to do a very basic version of ray-casting, however I need to do this about 10^7 times. What I need to do is to shoot rays from some point in a specific angular pattern and detect the first intersection with an object. That's basically it.
I have both a meshed version of the data, and a binary volume (from which I extracted the surface and created a mesh). I visualize everything via VTK/Paraview.

The question is: (How) can I use a standard Ray-Caster (for example a GPU-ray-caster) to accelerate this process? If so, can anybody direct me to some resource which instructs me how to set the angle of the ray and the starting point?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?